# Adding different data to CollectionView inside TableView

Tags: swift

I'm using CollectionView in TableView. I am adding more than one CollectionView as much as data.count. I also upload these images to imageView in CollectionView. But it adds the same data to every collectionView. How can I parse them? As you can see in the photo, there are two CollectionViews. The data added to both are the same. How can I add data to these CollectionViews separately?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RowJP.png)

**UITableViewCell**

```
class CategoryRow : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstColView: UICollectionView!
    var data = [String]()
}

extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  data.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellDav1", for: indexPath) as! anaSayfaCell
        let urlNew = URL(string: data[indexPath.row])
                   cell.denemeImage.sd_setImage(with: urlNew)

        return cell
    }



    func setData(data: [String])
    {
        self.data = data
        self.firstColView.reloadData()
            }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
extension anaSayfaViewController : UITableViewDelegate { }

extension anaSayfaViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return kategoriIsımYeni[section]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return kategoriIsımYeni.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CategoryRow
        cell.setData(data: davetiyefilee)
        return cell
    }

}

class anaSayfaViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

var davetiyefilee = [String]()
var davetiyefilee2 = [String]()

    var kategoriIsımYeni = [String]()
}
```

**UICollectionViewCell**

```
class anaSayfaCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var denemeImage: UIImageView!

}
```

Comment: what are the two arrays do you want to add different collectionview? I mean which data do you want to add 1st and 2nd

Comment: I updated topics, I want to view the variables. For example, davetiyefilee data will appear in 1.collectionView, davetiyefilee2 will appear in 2.collectionView.

Comment: I think I answered your newest question.please check

Comment: There is one CollectionView, I have to handle it without creating a CollectionView separately. @DilanAnuruddha